# How do I call Objective-C code from Matlab?

Tags: objective-c, matlab

I am working on Matlab and have Objective-C code to run. How can I call it from Matlab? Does "mex" work for it?

Comment: This is probably too broad. What kind of "Objective-C code"? Yes, you would use `mex`. It might be a bit out date, but [see here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/300054).

Comment: @horchler Why should it be too broad? If a method exists to execute arbitrary Objective-C code than why not using it?

Comment: @Trilarion: You're right. Maybe "unclear" is better? The question is just lacking specifics that would allow anyone to provide a specific answer.

Comment: Okay, then please why not telling a bit more about what you want to do? What data do you need to pass? What functionality to you want to expose to Matlab? I probably cannot help you but others may find it easier then.